# JAVA Type safety between two class at run time

Tags: java

I have two .jar files having same package structure and same class name.

Eg. `math.jar` and `state.jar`

package structure is `com.myorg.common`
and both jars having class called `Util`

Now, When i use the class in program...Object of which class will be created at run time?
and what if i wanted to create an object of specific class? (that is from math.jar)

Comment: It's like, having both open JDK and oracle JDK. Depends on which comes first in the class path.

Comment: The package structure is built this way exactly to avoid this problem.  The solution in your case is to create subpackages `com.myorg.common.math` and `com.myorg.common.state`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will depend on the order in which the jar files appear in the classpath. I believe the one that appears first in the classpath will be used. Any one classloader can only have a single class with a particular fully-qualified name.

Basically, this is a really bad idea - *don't* have the same class in the same package in multiple places; it's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Yep, first in the classpath is the one that's used. And +1 for the "don't do this".

Comment: See I will not be able to change the jar file. so how i can tall my compile to pick a class from particular jar ?

Comment: @Chakravyooh: The only way (at all) to do that in Java is to not have the two jars in the same class path, which you might be able to accomplish by using two class loaders. Whether this would work at all depends a great deal on the other contents of the two jars (i.e., if they depend on each other), because if you use multiple class loaders, neither jar will be able to "see" the contents of the other jar.

Comment: @Chakravyooh: Can you not change *either* jar file? How have you ended up in the situation where the same fully-qualified class name is in two different jar files? Why can't you change them?